# Safely replace python 3.6 with python3.7

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, python, python3

Due to some changes in Python I installed Python 3.7.1 on my computer but Python 3.6.7 is still installed. 
Most of the packages were installed with `pip3 install --user` before the update. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

I assume some modules are only in the 3.6 version, so sometimes I had to re-run pip and install some modules twice.

So now I'm unable to manage my xfce-Desktop properly as I'm constantly getting an error, which I assume comes up due to some kind of version conflict:

```
qohelet@linux:~$ xfce4-panel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/xfpanel-switch/xfpanel-switch/xfpanel-switch.py", line 29, in <module>
    import gi
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

By just importing it in both versions it's pretty clear that's the problem:

```
qohelet@linux:~$ python3.6
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
```

No problems so far. Now 3.7:

```
qohelet@linux:~$ python3.7
Python 3.7.1 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:21:55) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

Trying to just remove Python 3.6 with apt-get results in a disaster as basically all other programs that somehow rely on python (firefox, virtualbox and 500Mb of other software too) would be removed as well.

So what is the best way of doing the upgrade and removal properly?

Comment: It's probably too late now, but in the future, I would suggest leaving the system-installed Python alone.  I presume that is 3.6.7?  If you need to go ahead a version, then install it in your local home directory using [`conda`](https://www.anaconda.com/).  It would install software in a directory for just you to use.  Indeed, many system-level programs rely on Python so it'll end up causing you more headaches.  If you can still go back to 3.6.7, then I would suggest you try this instead.

Comment: @Ray - the default version installed was `Python 2.7.15rc1` - it was a little adventure to get the 3.6 running instead (especially in emacs). I'm not a huge fan of conda tbh as pip has so far worked just fine (well... till now I guess).

Comment: Ah!  I see!  What version of Ubuntu are you on?  You never mentioned that.  If you have Python2, you can install Python3 side-by-side by installing the `python3` package (that depends which Ubuntu you're on).  Then you manage packages using `pip3` rather than `pip`.  `conda`, as you probably know, can install `pip` to manage a local version of Python.  But yes, `conda` isn't for everyone.

Comment: As for where you're at, I'd suggest you go ahead and remove Python 3.6, including all of its dependencies.  Then install them all back before you restart.  In the absence of a better idea from someone else, this is what I'd do.  Anything else will result you digging yourself into a deeper hole (IMHO).

Comment: Ah, sorry. Edited it @Ray --> Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
So the transition from Python 2 to Python 3 worked I guess.

Comment: @Ray - I'd like to do that, but possibly without having to figure out which of my software will survive it. That's why I'm posting my question here